# perl : caching data in shared memory (ram)

Tags: linux, performance, perl, caching, shared-memory

i would like to know if it's possible to access a perl cached data from different scripts/crones ( using RAM, **not the DISK** ) 
i was able to access shared cached data using perl's module 'CHI' with the driver *FastMmap* .
it works fine, but it does *too much reading/writing* on the disk which makes it slow,
Using Ram cache drivers (like *Memory or RawMemory* ) is faster but the cache is visible only for the current process and it's child processes !

**so is it possible to make cached data in the memory '*RAM*' accessible to foreign perl scripts ?!**

*for installing CHI and FastMmap on linux*

```
sudo cpan -i CHI 
sudo cpan -i -f Cache::FastMmap
```

here is a small exemple,
execute it twice and it'll work fine unless you use other driver !

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CHI;
my $cache = CHI->new( driver => 'FastMmap',namespace => 'myApp' ,root_dir   => '/tmp/chifolder/chaches',cache_size => '5M');

if( !defined $cache->get('data') ){
        print "#creating caches  !\n";
        $cache->set( 'data' , "some shared data\n" );
}else{
          print "#caches already exists \n";
}
print  $cache->get('data');
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's called a "database".

Comment: i'm using cache to reduce my dataBase overload.

Comment: Would placing your `/tmp/chifolder/chaches` on a RAM disk (tmpfs) help?

Comment: it looks like a good idea,  
but i never used 'tmpfs'.  

i ll try to findout how to use a folder in RAM diskand and give it a try

Comment: @zakaria35 For a simple try you could use `sudo mount -t tmpfs none /tmp/chifolder/chaches` This reserves max. 50% of RAM for the ramdisk. But: first come, first serve, i.e. if you only have 20 % free RAM, then the ramdisk will only benefit from these 20%.

Comment: thanks @PerlDog, this works faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for youre help @PerlDog ,
i think that (*RAM disk ,tmpfs*) is what i needed,
i ll do more tests to know if the execution time is better and to make sure that i'm not using this the wrong way to avoid causing any troubles with the server...
i ll let you know the results